# Problem Getting '<blockquote>' IMGs to Show

Tags: css

On [this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/organic-networking-the-5-point-guide/) you can see a quote in a pink box. It's supposed to have quote mark images to the right and left of it.

This is the CSS:

```
blockquote {
    padding-left: 10px;
    color:#444;
    font-style: normal;
    background: #ff9999 url(quoleft.png) left top no-repeat;
}
blockquote div {
    padding: 0 48px;
    background: #ff9999 url(gu.png) right bottom no-repeat;
}
```

Would anyone be able to tell me why the images to the left and right of the quote are not showing?

Thanks in advance!
Tara

P.S.:I haven't actually designed the quote mark images yet but I'm using alternative images and they should show in their place.

Comment: Why are you using a `blockquote div` selector when your `<blockquote>` clearly contains a `<p>` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Problem #1](http://www.glamourunderground.com/wp-content/themes/primus/primus/quoleft.png)
- [Problem #2](http://www.glamourunderground.com/wp-content/themes/primus/primus/gu.png)
- Problem #3 - you are using `blockquote div` instead of `blockquote p`

Answer (score 4):

The image doesn't seem to exist.

Here's how to debug stuff like this:

**In Google Chrome**

1. Right-click the element  and choose "Inspect element"
2. A small window will appear, showing the full structure of the HTML document
3. Click on the `blockquote` element
4. The list to the right will show all CSS styles that apply to the element. It's a bit hidden, but you will find the `background` rule that you specified. The image link will be underlined.

   http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-1485353823.png
5. Right-click the image link, and select "Open in new window". A 404 page will pop up.

It works similar in all browsers; if you use Firefox, make sure you have the [Firebug extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firebug/).

Comment: Thanks for the guide @pekka . It didn't occur to me that the images might not be found because I assumed that it would come up with the 'not-found' image in the article if that was the case. But, for some reason it didn't this time.

Answer (score 1):

The [image](http://www.glamourunderground.com/wp-content/themes/primus/primus/quoleft.png) you are trying to reference does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The images are not located where you are saying they are. When you say `url(quoleft.png)` that refers to the directory you are currently in (http://www.glamourunderground.com/organic-networking-the-5-point-guide/). You are saying that that image is located at http://www.glamourunderground.com/organic-networking-the-5-point-guide/quoleft.png and it obviously is not.